# Продукты JetBrains не подключаются к базе данных

Tags: база-данных, jetbrains

Использую Ubuntu 16.04. PhpStorm был 2017.2 EAP, сейчас скачала 2017.1 Stable, так же пробовал через DataGrid подключаться к базам, но ничего не происходит, просто идет подключение, и в конце выдет ошибку о таймауте:

```
database.sqlite
Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

Появилось это буквально месяц назад, не стал заморачиваться т.к. в PhpStorm захожу редко и использовал PgAdmin для подключения к бд,он подключается нормально к базам PostgreSQL, PhpStorm ни к какой базе подключится не может, проверял на sqlite, MySQL, PostgreSQL.

Сразу скажу что проблема именно в JetBrains, потому что порты открыты(проверял telnet) и как говорил выше - PgAdmin коннектится, смущает в ошибке что хост всегда пишет localhost хотя у меня две базы, одна Vagrant, другая на удаленном сервере.

Дополню скринами подключения и настройками PostgreSQL:
[image: connections]

[image: settings]

Comment: так может просто в настройках надо что-то поменять?

Comment: @Grundy менял версии штормов, версии драйверов PostgreSQL которые они используют, пробовал пересоздавать подключения

Comment: так а в настройках подключения что указано?

Comment: @Grundy добавил скриншоты

Comment: при "Test connection" ту же ошибку дает?

Comment: @Grundy да, пробовал качать последнюю версию драйвера с https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html та же беда, ошибка в java скорее всего, но где именно не найду, как вариант поставить другую версию java думаю

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит писать `localhost`?

Для удобства - зайди в программу `pgAdmin` и там на созданном тобою сервере нажми правой кнопкой мыши -> `Properties...` (См. рисунок 1). В отрывшемся окне выбери в верхней панели `Connection` и скопируй все данные в свой IDE (см. рисунок 2).

Если все же не получилось ничего сделать - проверь, что сервер активирован.

Рисунок 1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рисунок 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

через ssh туннель подключись[image: введите сюда описание изображения].